# Force delete file localized in network folder by code

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a very old winform application, that the users work directly with the exe file that is localized in network folder.

My big Problem is every time I want to release a new version.

The dlls of the app are locked by the users and I get the following error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

(I use another app to release the new version).

I want to create a script that will force delete the files even some users are still working on the application.

I don't mind what language to write with, I tried PowerShell, C#, but find no answers.

Comment: I don't think you can force delete a file if it's in use by a process. Not sure if [This article](http://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-delete-file-in-use-windows-rename-locked-corrupt-3605330/) is useful?

Comment: You may not be able to delete the file, but Windows will allow you to rename a file currently in use, (e.g., myapp.exe to myapp-old.exe). Then the next time the application is loaded it will use the new files.

Comment: Have you tried to kill the executables process by either Stop-Process in powershell or process.Kill() in c#. Just asking before I fire up some examples as an answer if you had already gone down this path.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that since in your question you are asking how to force delete a deployed assembly which would give the app in use an unexpected shutdown ANYWAY then...

Try by killing the process of the exe first before the deploy. In c# for example (untested/not optimized until I have a free second so just an initial thought):

```
while(Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name").Length > 0)
{
 //keep murderizing process while they are running
 foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("whatever"))
 {
   process.Kill();
 }
}

//Should be free now to delete
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  I was thinking of an idea like this, but the processes are in the user's computers. How can I access those processes ?

Answer (score 0):

> Hello! In the remote hosts you can try to do like this:

[How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-Proce](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18146/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-Proce)

> Or like this (using powershell - add a System.Management.Automation.dll in C#):

```
using System.Management.Automation;

var xs = PowerShell.Create().AddScript("(gwmi win32_process -ComputerName Host | ? {$_.name -like 'proceesname*'}).Terminate()").AddCommand("out-string");
            Collection<PSObject> results = xs.Invoke();

            foreach (var str in results)
            {


                     Console.WriteLine(str);
                     Console.ReadLine();

            }
```

> Or you can use psexec.exe to connect at the remote pc:

```
string queryString =
                   "SELECT Name" +
                   "  FROM Win32_Process";

                ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();

                connOptions.Username = "user@domain.local";
                connOptions.Password = "password";

                SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery(queryString);

                ManagementScope scope = new System.Management.ManagementScope(@"\\Hostname\root\CIMV2", connOptions);

                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
                ManagementObjectCollection processes = searcher.Get();

                foreach (ManagementObject mo in processes)
                {

                    if (mo["Name"].ToString() == "mmc.exe")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(mo["Name"].ToString());

                        Process cmd = new Process();

                        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "processname.exe";

                        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                        cmd.Start();
                        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("psexec.exe \\\\Hostname cmd /c taskkill /IM " + mo["Name"].ToString() + " /f" );
                        cmd.WaitForExit();
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }

                }
```